# Underful hbox with revtex4

Tags: floats

When I insert a figure into my two column report I get underful hbox error. Even if I scale this figure to 0.1/pagewidth I still get this error. How can I remove it?

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{FEKII}
\caption{ FEKII peptide structure showing hydrophobic face (top) and hydrophilic face (bottom) at pH 7}
\label{fig:Fmoc}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: That code should not produce an underfull box, I would expect it to produce an overfull box as \columnwidth is typically less than .5\textwidth to allow for a separation between the columns. You shoudl anyway use width=\columnwidth for a full width single column

Comment: Its not actually the picture it it is saying is underful, but upon inserting this figure it makes the text above it produce errors

Comment: It is very hard to comment on what is wrong with code that you have not shown. Please see [how to make a minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/#answer-3225)